# extending executable attribute to all users

Tags: linux, chmod

I have a directory structure, owned by root, where some files are executable by root, and all files/directories are readable by all users.

What is a good way to make all executable files in it (but not other files) executable by all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (as root):

```
find /your/directory -executable -type f -exec chmod o+x {} +
```

Comment: Better: `+` instead of `\;` will batch up `chmod` processes, like `xargs`.